# Convert CSV based on the filtering condition

Tags: mulesoft

Could some one please help me to map the below csv to JSON.

Need to filter based on the below filtering condition on all the five fields.

1. Integer
2. Length 5 digits
3. First two digits starts with “65”

Input:

field1,field2,field3,field4,field5

123,ABC12,4512300000,234,567

567,4532100000,DEF34,123,432

Output:

[

{

"OrderNUmber": "4512300000"

},

{

"OrderNUmber": "4532100000"

}

]

Comment: Did you mean any of the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am think that there will be just one field in each row that matches all three conditions, hence selector `[0]`

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::Runtime
fun isNumber(value): Boolean = try(() -> isInteger(value)) orElse false
---
payload map ((item, index) -> 
                    OrderNumber: (valuesOf(item) 
                                        filter (( value ) -> (isNumber(value) 
                                            and (value startsWith  "65") 
                                            and sizeOf(value) == 5)))[0])
```